# pandas make column index a multiindex object

Tags: pandas

using

```
pd_now.set_index("a")
```

We could make column "a" adding to the index of the "row index", making "row index" a multiindex object

However, I did not find any way to add a row "b" to the "column index", making "column index" a multiindex object. Did I miss anything? Thank you.

Comment: `df.set_index(['a','b'])`?

Comment: what i mean is, i want the df.columns (the df.columns is a index object) to be a multi-index. df.set_index(['a','b']) just makes the df.index a multiindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `T` and `set_index`

```
df.T.set_index(['a','b']).T
```

If you need add one

```
df.T.set_index('b',append=True).T
```